# Trigger Parse.com query when database is updated

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery, pfobject

I'm building an app where I need to get new PFObjects as users upload them. Currently what I'm doing is running a query every 10 seconds to query the database for new objects.

As you could imagine, this is extremely inefficient and heavy on requests.

I was wondering if there was any way of triggering a query if the database in parse has been updated? For example a user saves an object to parse, which triggers a query on all other users devices to download the new object.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend when you new item is created in a data you should post a push notification with to inform others that new data and when you app get  push notification app should pull new data.

```
let push:PFPush = PFPush()
        let dic:[String:NSNumber] = ["content-available" :NSNumber(integer: 1)]
        push.setData(dic)
        push.sendPushInBackground()
```

And on `didReceiveRemoteNotification` check for `content-available` 
if it has value the fetch new content

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo:NSDictionary!) {

    var notification:NSDictionary = userInfo.objectForKey("aps") as NSDictionary

    if (notification.objectForKey("content-available") != nil){
    }
}
```